# How to get a working HttpsUrlConnection with Steam Web API?

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection, steam-web-api

im currently trying to implement the Steam Web API using the given code in the following repository -> https://github.com/Overv/SteamWebAPI/blob/master/SteamAPISession.cs into my Android app and im getting different exceptions dependend on using the given wep api ip ( 63.228.223.110 ) or the adress ( https://api.steampowered.com/ ) itself.

my code actually looks like this in the given method when building up a connection to the web api:

```
    private String steamRequest( String get, String post ) {

    final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
    int numberOfTries = 0;

    HttpsURLConnection request = null;

    while(numberOfTries < MAX_RETRIES) {

        if (numberOfTries != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Retry -> " + numberOfTries);
        }

        try {
            request = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://api.steampowered.com/" + get).openConnection(); //or 63.228.223.110/ ???

            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            String host = "api.steampowered.com";
            int port = 443;
            int header = 0;

            socketFactory.createSocket(new Socket(host, port), host, port, false);
            request.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            request.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
            request.setDoOutput(false);
            //            request.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.steampowered.com:443");
            //            request.setRequestProperty("Protocol-Version", "httpVersion");
            request.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            request.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            request.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-us");
            request.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Steam 1291812 / iPhone");
            request.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

            if (post != null) {
                byte[] postBytes;

                try {
                    request.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    postBytes = post.getBytes("US-ASCII");

                    //                    request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postBytes.length));
                    request.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postBytes.length);
                    request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(request.getOutputStream());
                    out.print(post);
                    out.close();

                    //                    DataOutputStream requestStream = new DataOutputStream(request.getOutputStream());
                    ////                    OutputStreamWriter stream = new OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
                    ////                    stream.write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.length);
                    //                    requestStream.write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.length);
                    //                    requestStream.close();

                    message++;

                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try {
                int statusCode = request.getResponseCode();
                InputStream is;
                Log.d(TAG, "The response code of the status code is" + statusCode);
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    is = request.getErrorStream();
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(is));
                }

                //            String src = null;
                //            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
                //            out.write(src);
                //            out.close();

                Scanner inStream = new Scanner(request.getInputStream());
                String response = "";
                while (inStream.hasNextLine()) {
                    response += (inStream.nextLine());
                }

                //                String src;
                //                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
                //                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                //                while ((src = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //                    builder.append(src);
                //                }

                //                String jsonData = builder.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, response); //jsonData

                //                in.close();

                return response; //jsonData

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (request != null) {
                request.disconnect();
            }
        }

        numberOfTries++;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Max retries reached. Giving up on connecting to Steam Web API...");
    return null;
}
```

following exception occurs when using https://api.steampowered.com/ as url:

> W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamOAuth2/GetTokenWithCredentials/v0001
>   D/OptionsFragment﹕ Failed to log in!

i've really tried and researched on those issues, but i just can't get a solution. If someone got a good hint on helping to solve these exceptions please let me know!

**EDIT:**
I've researched some more!

Looking up on https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/webapi#creating the direct ip adress shouldn't be used and therefore only the DNS name itself (for further clarification look on the given link). Hence, looking up on the API interface list itself -> http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v0001/?format=json there doesn't seem to be a given Interface with a method called ISteamOAuth2/GetTokenWithCredentials.(Or not anymore!) Only ISteamUserAuth and ISteamUserOAuth which seem to handle Authentication stuff.

I will update this post again if i should get a working connection and handling with the steam web api.

Cheers!